# How to paginate dynamodb results using aws sdk sendCommand

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

How do I paginate when scanning dynamodb with the send command?  Looking online solid examples seem to be using the older versions of the sdk library.

Many thanks,

**my code snippet below**

The results are as expected not all rows in dynamodb.

```
  const scanCommand = new ScanCommand({
    TableName: 'Members',
  });

  const members = await dynamoClient.send(scanCommand);

  for (const member of members.Items) {
      ...
  }
```

Comment: Use [ExclusiveStartKey](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-dynamodb/interfaces/scancommandinput.html#exclusivestartkey) in your ScanCommandInput.

Comment: The process you use is the same regardless of the library at least as far as v2 vs v3. The only difference is that you can now load only the parts of the SDK you need. The underlying API remains the same. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64986481/how-to-implement-dynamodb-pagination-in-material-ui-table/64987623#64987623) for some additional explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for everyone's help, this was the solution that worked for me.  The change was to call the `send` command recursively and passing the LastEvaluatedKey value into the method as the ExclusiveStartKey property.
The recursive loop continues until the LastEvaluatedKey is `undefined`.

The change is using async/await, arrow functions (ES6), a self invoking function and a do/ while loop.

**Code snippet**

```
(async () => {

  const getMembers = async (_key: any) => {

    const scanCommand = new ScanCommand({
      TableName: 'Members',
      Limit: 10,
      ExclusiveStartKey: _key,
    });

    const results = await dynamoClient.send(scanCommand);

    // do stuff

    return results.LastEvaluatedKey;
  }

  let key;
  do {
    key = await getMembers(key);
  }
  while (typeof key !== "undefined");

})();
```

note - I think the `Limit` should probably be large rather than small to reduce the number of calls to dynamodb which I assume would reduce AWS costs